# Interested in flashlight/torch that uses iPhone LED flash

Tags: iphone

I am looking for a physical flashlight or torch that uses the same kind of LED light as the one housed in the iPhone's flash.  I do a lot of shadow puppetry, and the iPhone's LED makes very crisp shadows, while in other LED torches the shadows blur.

Curious if anyone has any leads, or if anyone knows about the specific *kind* of LED that is used in the iPhone's flash.

Comment: For what it’s worth, it is a quad-LED flash. See [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+X+Teardown/98975#s182909) on iFixit. But not sure if it is custom Apple, or available.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's the type of LED as how bright it is for an [apparent] single unit. Torches tend to spread them out in front of a reflector - that would be the main difference. single-point-light will give sharp shadows, diffuse light won't.

Comment: Any more leads on this? Down the rabbit hole of a similar problem. Other lights are diffusing shadows and require my subject to be very close to the surface they cast a shadow on while my iphone flashlight creates crisp shadows at a much greater distance..

Answer (score 1):

Your request sounds unconventional. The iPhone flash is a specific part of the gadget that's hard to fake. But let me ask, for what purpose are you looking for this particular flash? I think it's much better to find a flashlight with multiple modes, like a flash, diffused light, and a well-directed direct white beam. Well, I can just show you my favorite flashlight. I always take mine [https://www.amazon.com/Vont-Flashlight-Flashlights-Water-Resistant-Accessories/dp/B089T8HDBV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089T8HDBV) when I go camping outdoors. Also, I use it when I need to photograph someone in the dark. Of course, I don't like the red-eye effect like in all digital photos. So using a flashlight when shooting at night helps to avoid that.